# Exoplayer para Cordova no selecciona la mejor calidad conforme a la red y bug del buffer superior

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Resulta que estoy implementando una aplicación con `Cordova` para `Android` y en esta utilizo `Exoplayer` para reproducir una URL the Smooth Streaming

```
console.log(videoUrl);
    var params = {
      url: videoUrl ,
      hideTimeout: 2000,
      showBuffering: false,
      controller: { // If this object is not present controller will not be visible
        streamImage: 'http://url.to/channel.png',
        streamTitle: 'Channel',
        streamDescription: '',
        hideProgress: false, // Hide entire progress timebar
        hidePosition: false, // If timebar is visible hide current position from it
        hideDuration: false, // If timebar is visible Hide stream duration from it
        controlIcons: {
             // Buttons not included in configuration will show up as default ExoPlayer buttons
        },
        textColor: '#ffff0000', // These colors can be any valid Android color
        buttonsColor: '#E6FFE6', // This example uses hex values including alpha (first byte)
        bufferingColor: '#ff0000ff' // Alpha of 'ff' makes it 100% opaque
      }
    };//fin de parms


 // window.plugins.exoplayer.setStream(,null);
    try{
      window.ExoPlayer.show(params, successCallback, errorCallback);

    }catch(exception){
      console.log(exception);
    }
```

Por el videoUrl le paso un SmoothStreaming.ism/Manifest pero siempre me selecciona la mejor calidad sin importar la conexión.

He investigado y no he encontrado nada de parsear la URI para que se realice esta tarea como si ocurre en Android con java que utiliza la clase SsmediaSource. **¿Falta algo aparte de esto?** o **¿Sabéis si el plugin tiene algún tipo de error?** porque con el `showbuffering` lo tengo en false pero me sigue saliendo arriba.